# What are the plans to improve the onscreen keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch

I just got an Aquarius M10 Ubuntu Edition, and though I am very positively surprised by the current state of the OS, the onscreen keyboard is quite a dealbreaker. I can work around the lack of arrows and other features for now, but **the keyboard takes almost half of the screen in any orientation** without any visible way to resize it...

Is there any way I can stay tuned about improvement plans and ongoing work on this topic (and eventually contribute)?

Alternatively,will Ubuntu Touch support third-party keyboards in the foreseeable future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [bug report](http://pad.lv/1574606) related to this issue.
Also you might want to join this [team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone) and follow their [mailing list](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/) to stay updated.